# Using an array in a MongoDB aggregation query with $or

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use an array in a MongoDB C# aggregation query with an $or statement. My code is as follows:

```
var groupsArray = new BsonArray
                          {new BsonDocument { { "role", 1 } },
                                new BsonDocument { { "role", 2 } },
                                new BsonDocument { { "role", 3 } }
                          };

      var bsonOr = new BsonDocument
                     {
                       {
                         "$or",
                         groupsArray
                       }
                     };

      var match = new BsonDocument { { "$match", 
                                      new BsonDocument { { "$or", bsonOr } } } };
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 
Command 'aggregate' failed: exception: bad query: 
BadValue $or needs an array (response: 
{ "errmsg" : "exception: bad query: BadValue $or needs an array", 
"code" : 16810, "ok" : 0.0 }).
```

Is there a specific way to use an array in this query that I'm missing?

Comment: match should be `var match = new BsonDocument {{"$match", bsonOr}};` ?

Comment: why are you using $or?  This should be a basic $in:  `{$match:{role:{$in:[1,2,3]}}}`   but BatScream is right - you are putting $or in there twice.

Comment: @BatScream thanks -- if you post that as a solution I'll mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `or` was being added twice. The code was changed to

```
var groupsArray = new BsonArray();

      foreach (var g in groups)
      {
        groupsArray.Add(new BsonDocument() { { "role", g.Id.ToString() } });
      }
      var bsonOr = new BsonDocument
                     {
                       {
                         "$or",
                         groupsArray
                       }
                     };

      var match = new BsonDocument { { "$match", bsonOr } };
```

And worked as I hoped.

Comment: Better that a C# Programmer posted it.